# django admin add many to many field not select

Tags: django, django-admin

Lets say I have a model:

```
class MyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = Models.ManyToManyField(Members)

class Members(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here when I register `MyGroup` in `admin` I get a dropdown  in `members`.
But I dont want this. In my admin I want to add `members` in `MyGroup` models.

Like say I get a field in `MyGroup` in admin and when I give input and save it, it should be added.

Is there a way I can do it. Same problem can also be solved for `ForeignKey` .
Any help will be appriciated.

P.S. I dont want to use `Inline`

Thank you..

Comment: Why you don't want to use `InlineModelAdmin`? It does exactly what you want. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: I can use `Inline` but what If I want to do this in 3 models. I mean foreign key to `Members` for 3 models. I can not register `Members` 3 time. That is  the complexity I guess. Any solution ?